# I've screwed up my system by manually downloading and installing gcc. How do I uninstall a specific version?

Tags: dpkg, gcc

I've screwed up my system by manually downloading and installing gcc:
gcc-11-base/now 11.3.0-3 amd64

Info about my ubuntu :

```
uname -r
5.18.6-051806-generic

lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

What I see:

```
# dpkg-query -l gcc-11*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version         Architecture Description
+++-=================-===============-============-===============================================
rU  gcc-11            11.2.0-7ubuntu2 amd64        GNU C compiler
rU  gcc-11-base:amd64 11.3.0-3        amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
iF  gcc-11-base:i386  11.2.0-7ubuntu2 i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
un  gcc-11-doc        <none>          <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-11-locales    <none>          <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-11-multilib   <none>          <none>       (no description available)
```

As shown above, I see 2 installations of base:

```
gcc-11-base:amd64 11.3.0-3
gcc-11-base:i386  11.2.0-7ubuntu2
```

I want to remove "gcc-11-base:amd64 11.3.0-3" and leave "gcc-11-base:i386" untouched.

Here's what I tried:

```
# dpkg -r gcc-11-base:amd64
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of gcc-11-base:amd64:
 libubsan1:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libtsan0:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libquadmath0:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 liblsan0:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libitm1:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libgomp1:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libgfortran5:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libgcc-s1:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libgcc-11-dev:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libcc1-0:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libatomic1:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 libasan6:amd64 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 gcc-11 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 g++-11 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
 cpp-11 depends on gcc-11-base (= 11.2.0-7ubuntu2).
```

It looks like it is trying to remove "11.2.0-7ubuntu2"

I'm still a newbie so, please go easy :)

Comment: So what is the Ubuntu version? `5.18.6-051806-generic` is not an Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: How do I see that?

Comment: do: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: done, edited the question above.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish

Comment: Not sure if it helps but the gcc I downloaded and installed is "gcc-11-base_11.3.0-3_amd64.deb". This is the culprit that ruined everything. Most "sudo apt " commands are not working now.  E.g. running  "--fix-broken install" or similar.

Comment: You could consider removing *both* and then putting back the one you want after.  I mean, they're both compilers and thus not required parts of the system (i.e., some people don't program and wouldn't have installed either).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, I don't know if this is good practice, but it worked for me.

```
dpkg --remove --ignore-depends=libubsan1,libtsan0,libstdc++6,libstdc++-11-dev,libquadmath0,liblsan0,libitm1,libgomp1,libgfortran5,libgcc-s1,libgcc-11-dev,libcc1-0,libatomic1,libasan6,gcc-11,g++-11,cpp-11 gcc-11-base

dpkg --remove --ignore-depends=gcc,g++-11,g++  gcc-11
```

Explanation :

- I didn't find a way to remove a specific version, so I decided to nuke gc-11 out of existence.
- dpkg --remove wont work because of all the dependencies. So, I had to add all ignore commands.
- Do this only as the last resort since this threatens system stability in general.

Hope this helps, my system is now stable.